# Replacing first occurrence of comma in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to replace the first occurrence of a comma in all lines from a file with another pattern, `','`, in shell script.

Example, input:

```
apple,orange
```

Expected output:

```
apple','orange
```

How can sed be used to achieve this?

Comment: Literally the [first link](http://www.theunixschool.com/2014/08/sed-examples-remove-delete-chars-from-line-file.html) if you google it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  People are more receptive to questions like this if you show what you've tried and explain why it is not working (either what the error message is, or why the result is wrong).  In this case, the requisite code is pretty straight-forward, as long as you use appropriate quoting.  So, what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sed** is your friend. The result can be stored in a new file.

Give a try to this tested command below:

```
sed s/,/\',\'/ file.txt > result.txt
```

The **sed** man page contains information.

The test output:

```
$ cat input.txt
apple,orange,house 
foo,bar,woops
$ sed s/,/\',\'/ input.txt > result.txt
$ cat result.txt 
apple','orange,house
foo','bar,woops
```